# Can we use CASE statement to decide whether WHERE clause exist in the query or not in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to use case statement for deciding whether where clause exists in the query or not

Something like this

```
    declare @Rasearch nvarchar(10)='sekhar'

    select  
        ID, Username 
    from 
        SampleUser S 
    CASE WHEN @Rasearch!=''THEN
        where  S.Username like '%'+@Rasearch+'%' 
    END
```

I don't know whether it is legal to use CASE for deciding WHEN clause, but previously I use CASE to decide sorting order in ORDER BY. When I tried this I got error saying incorrect syntax near CASE

Actually I am trying to accomplish following

I want to use case statement to accomplish following

```
    declare @Rasearch nvarchar(10)=''

    if @Rasearch <>''
      begin
         select ID,Username from SampleUser S
         where S.Username like  '%'+@Rasearch+'%' 
      end
    else
      begin
         select ID,Username from SampleUser S
       end
```

Comment: No, you **cannot** do this since `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL - it can return different **values** - but it's **NOT** a flow control statement like it might be in other languages - it cannot be used to optionally execute varying portions of code

Answer (score 1):

The logic is the same as using `and`

```
declare @Rasearch nvarchar(10)='sekhar'

select ID, Username from SampleUser S
where @Rasearch<>'' and S.Username like '%'+@Rasearch+'%'
```

You can use `case` in a `where` clause the syntax is

```
declare @Rasearch nvarchar(10)='sekhar'

select ID,Username from SampleUser S
where S.Username like case when @Rasearch<>'' then '%'+@Rasearch+'%' else '' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `case` statement for this.  The correct logic is:

```
     select ID, Username
     from SampleUser S
     where @Rasearch = '' or S.Username like  '%'+@Rasearch+'%' ;
```

Note:

For this logic, you don't even need the `or` statement -- unless `S.Username` can be `NULL`.  The following will fetch all non-NULL user names when `@Rasearch` is `''`:

```
    select ID, Username
     from SampleUser S
     where S.Username like  '%'+@Rasearch+'%' ;
```